# How to pass the String value, from the Form1 to Form2 class?

Tags: java, netbeans

How can i pass or use again the result value  of the String (Val1 variable) from the Form1 to Form2? Help Pls.

**Form1**

```
public class Form1(){

String Val1;

Val1=JCombobox.getSelectedItem().toString();

Form2 f2=new Form2();

f2.setVisible(true);


}
```

**Form2**

```
public class Form2(){

//(Code Goes Here)Value of Variable Val1 supposedly goes here how can i do that?    


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Form2 only has a zero argument initializer right now - and needs one that takes a string.

You will need the following as an initializer

```
public Form2(String s){
// DO SOMETHING WITH S
}
```